# Редактирование баз данных tempdb

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет ребята. Настраиваю sql сервер. Но на нем уже есть база.

В документации описано о настройке базы данных model и tempdb
Сейчас значения такие:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrtJn.png

Нужно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу ли Я внести эти изменения в tempdb. Не будет ли проблем с основной базой?
Основная база 500гб

```
Select session_id,
wait_type,
wait_duration_ms,
blocking_session_id,
resource_description,
        ResourceType = Case
When Cast(Right(resource_description, Len(resource_description) - Charindex(':', resource_description, 3)) As Int) - 1 % 8088 = 0 Then 'Is PFS Page'
            When Cast(Right(resource_description, Len(resource_description) - Charindex(':', resource_description, 3)) As Int) - 2 % 511232 = 0 Then 'Is GAM Page'
            When Cast(Right(resource_description, Len(resource_description) - Charindex(':', resource_description, 3)) As Int) - 3 % 511232 = 0 Then 'Is SGAM Page'
            Else 'Is Not PFS, GAM, or SGAM page'
            End
From sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
Where wait_type Like 'PAGE%LATCH_%'
And resource_description Like '2:%'
```

Не выдал ничего, может быть и менять ничего не нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам стоит установить больший начальный размер файлов tempdb. Особенно это важно для LOG-файла. Вообще следует избегать ситуаций неконтролируемого прироста файлов БД.

Я бы рекомендовал установить начальный размер файлов в 512 Мб с приростом 256 Мб. Через пару недель под рабочей нагрузкой посмотрите на состояние файлов и, в случае увеличения их размера, задайте им новый размер, несколько больший текущего (+256 Мб).

**Важно!** Файлы данных (ROWS Data) должны быть одинакового размера.

Запрос из sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks ничего не говорит о проблемах относящихся к размеру файлов tempdb. Он выводит текущие (на момент выполнения) ожидающие таски, причем ожидающие latch-ей. А в вашем случае со временем скорее всего начнет выстреливать LOGMGR_RESERVE_APPEND, WRITELOG или LOGBUFFER.

Указанные изменения в tempdb никак не касаются основной БД. Возможно некоторое замедление на время расширения файла лога. Транзакции, которые должны быть записаны в лог, будут ожидать завершения операции прироста.